# How to replace list/tuple with dictionaries, in working code, to improve its performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, dictionary

I have this code which works fine and is minimal and reproducible. It uses `lists` and `tuples`. Given the slowness of lists and tuples on large amounts of data, i would like to change the whole setting and use `dictionaries` to speed up performance.

So I'd like to convert this block of queues into something similar that uses dictionaries.

The purpose of the code is to create the variables `x` and `y` (calculation of mathematical data) and add them to a list, using an append and tuples. I then mine the numbers for certain purposes.

How can I add `dictionaries` where needed and replace them with `list/append` codes? Thank you!

**VERSION WITH TUPLE AND LIST**

```
mylist = {('Jack', 'Grace', 8, 9, '15:00'): [0, 1, 1, 5], 
         ('William', 'Dawson', 8, 9, '18:00'): [1, 2, 3, 4], 
         ('Natasha', 'Jonson', 8, 9, '20:45'): [0, 1, 1, 2]}

new = []

for key, value in mylist.items():

    #create variables and perform calculations
    calc_x= sum(value)/ len(value)
    calc_y = (calc_x *100) / 2

    #create list with 3 tuples inside
    if calc_x > 0.1:
        new.append([[key], [calc_x], [calc_y]])

print(new)
print(" ")

#example for call calc_x
print_x = [tuple(i[1]) for i in new]
print(print_x)
```

I was trying to write something like this, but I don't think it fits, so don't even look at it.I have two requests if possible:

- I would like `sum(value)/ len(value)` and `(calc_x *100) / 2` to continue to have their own variables `calc_x` and `calc_y`, so that they can invoke **individually** in the append as you can see
- In the `new` variable, i would like to be able to call the variables when i are needed, such as `for example i do for print_x = [tuple(i[1]) for i in new]`. Thank you

Comment: append is for list not dict , you have 2 update dict or `new['key'] = ... `

Comment: "Given the slowness of lists and tuples on large amounts of data, I would like to change the whole setting and use dictionaries to speed up performance" This is not understandable. Data structures do not have a speed; algorithms do. Certain data structures make certain algorithms possible. Whether it helps for your code will depend on the purpose of the code.

Comment: "Please don't leave me negative ratings. I don't think I deserve them. If there is something to correct, I APOLOGIZE already in advance, and I will immediately improve and correct the question" Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366889, and please try not to take downvotes personally. This site is **not a discussion forum**, which means - among other things - we have a very high standard for questions. Very often, it is really impossible to ask the question, if you actually have it - because if you knew how to ask properly, you would know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to improve performance, you can use `Pandas` (or `Numpy`) to vectorize math operations:

```
import pandas as pd

# Transform your dataset to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mylist, orient='index')

# Compute some operations
df['x'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df['y'] = df['x'] * 50

# Filter out and export
out = df.loc[df['x'] > 0.1, ['x', 'y']].to_dict('split')
new = dict(zip(out['index'], out['data']))
```

Output:

```
>>> new
{('Jack', 'Grace', 8, 9, '15:00'): [1.75, 87.5],
 ('William', 'Dawson', 8, 9, '18:00'): [2.5, 125.0],
 ('Natasha', 'Jonson', 8, 9, '20:45'): [1.0, 50.0]}
```

A numpy version:

```
import numpy as np

# transform keys to numpy array (special hack to keep tuples)
keys = np.empty(len(mylist), dtype=object)
keys[:] = tuple(mylist.keys())

# transform values to numpy array
vals = np.array(tuple(mylist.values()))

x = np.mean(vals, axis=1)
y = x * 50

# boolean mask to exclude some values
m = x > 0.1

out = np.vstack([x, y]).T
new = dict(zip(keys[m].tolist(), out[m].tolist()))
print(new)

# Output
{('Jack', 'Grace', 8, 9, '15:00'): [1.75, 87.5],
 ('William', 'Dawson', 8, 9, '18:00'): [2.5, 125.0],
 ('Natasha', 'Jonson', 8, 9, '20:45'): [1.0, 50.0]}
```

A python version:

```
new = {}
for k, v in mylist.items():
    x = sum(v) / len(v)
    y = x * 50
    if x > 0.1:
        new[k] = [x, y]
print(new)

# Output
{('Jack', 'Grace', 8, 9, '15:00'): [1.75, 87.5],
 ('William', 'Dawson', 8, 9, '18:00'): [2.5, 125.0],
 ('Natasha', 'Jonson', 8, 9, '20:45'): [1.0, 50.0]}
```

**Update**: How to extract `x`:

```
# Pandas
>>> df['x'].tolist()  # or simply df['x'] to extract the column
[1.75, 2.5, 1.0]

# Python
>>> [v[0] for v in new.values()]
[1.75, 2.5, 1.0]
```

Comment: The idea of ​​using pandas is very interesting. I could also show me the versions with numpy only (without pandas) how could I do? I would be grateful. I would be happy to accept and upvote your answer. Thank you

Comment: Of course you also remain the solution with pandas. Thanks for the kindness. I appreciate

Comment: In your numpy are we missing the condition x > 0.1? Sorry to say this, but I've never used Numpy and I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: Now yours is a great, very comprehensive answer. I will accept you as a solution. I already voted for you. But there are 2 small things missing in your answer that I requested in my question. How can I print only x value ([1.75, 2.5, 1.0]) with pandas and with dictionary? Can you add this please? Thank you. You are great! :)

Comment: I updated my answer according your last comment. Can you check it please?